# В чем разница между парными и непарными тегами в html?

Tags: html

В интернете пишут только о разнице в синтаксисе, а я хочу узнать о разнице в их функциональности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Парные теги являются как-бы элементами конструктора, который можно собрать как захочется, а непарные теги являются уже готовыми элементами, в которые не добавишь чего-то нового.
Например, в тег `<div>` могут быть вставлены другие теги, например, `<p>`, а в него может быть вставлен текст:

```
<div> <p>Текст</p> </div>
```

Тег `<img>` представляет собой готовый контейнер для картинки, в теге можно изменять его атрибуты:

```
<img src="URL" alt="альтернативный текст">
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам)